# What are the practical limitations of complementing quantum computations with memristors?

Tags: quantum-gate, experimental-realization, architecture

Considering the current state of research into quantum memristors, and the advantages/disadvantages of quantum and memristor driven computing architectures:

[Quantum Memristors](https://escholarship.org/content/qt9cb4k842/qt9cb4k842_noSplash_c9655d27c36a95af34e033c62928942b.pdf)

[Quantum Memristor Circuits](https://escholarship.org/content/qt41h5t5z3/qt41h5t5z3_noSplash_b780c09866e96f8eac3fcbcc0c3bc190.pdf)

[Quantum Computing vs. Memory focused computation of Memristors](https://www.labs.hpe.com/pdf/Beyond_the_qubit.pdf)

**From a practical implementation point of view, what are current the limits of 'boosting' or 'complementing' quantum computations with memristors?**